# SQL Server: Count distinct dates in a group

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I'm still new to SQL so I may be doing this wrong but...

I need to get a distinct count of appointment dates. So John for cust.id 1 should have a count of 3 appointment dates and Sara should have a count of 2 appointment dates for cust.id 1.

Temp table (EC):

```
 |cust.id | emp_name | emp_id |   APPT_DATE    | Procedure_Code | something1|
 |:------:|:--------:|:------:|:--------------:|:--------------:|:---------:|
 |    1   |   john   |  100   |  2/2 00:00:00  |      a0        |    w/e    |
 |    1   |   john   |  100   |  2/3 00:00:00  |      b1        |    w/e    |
 |    1   |   john   |  100   |  2/4 00:00:00  |      c2        |    w/e    |
 |    1   |   Sara   |  200   |  2/2 00:00:00  |      d3        |    w/e    |
 |    1   |   Sara   |  200   |  2/3 00:00:00  |      e4        |    w/e    |
```

Answer I'm looking for:

```
 | cust.id | emp_name | emp_id | CNT |   APPT_DATE   | Procedure_Code |
 |:-------:|:--------:|:------:|:---:|:-------------:|:--------------:|
 |    1    |   john   |   100  |  3  |  2/2 00:00:00 |     a0101      |
 |    1    |   john   |   100  |  3  |  2/3 00:00:00 |     b1234      |
 |    1    |   john   |   100  |  3  |  2/4 00:00:00 |     c0101      |
 |    1    |   Sara   |   200  |  2  |  2/2 00:00:00 |     d0101      |
 |    1    |   Sara   |   200  |  2  |  2/3 00:00:00 |     e1234      |
```

My Code:

```
SELECT cust_id
       ,emp_name
       ,emp_id
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT APPT_DATE)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, APPT_DATE) AS CNT
       ,APPT_DATE
       ,Procedure_Code 
FROM #EC 
ORDER BY cust_id
```

Comment: But why your Procedure_Code being change?

Comment: you wanted a distinct count of appt date by cust id or emp id ? Your description said "cust id" but your result looks like it is "emp id". EDIT : looks like both ! correct ?

Comment: @Loser customers come in to get different things done. Such as if you go to an auto repair shop one day to get new brake pads and then get an oil change. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @Squirrel yes it's both! sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,b.CNT 
from(
    SELECT cust_id
           ,emp_name
           ,
           ,APPT_DATE
           ,Procedure_Code 
    FROM #EC
     ) as a inner join (select count(distinct appt_date)as cnt, emp_id from #EC group by emp_id)as b
  on a.emp_id = b.emp_id
```

I think the above code can help you.

Answer (score 0):

remove APPT_DATE from PARTITION BY

```
COUNT(DISTINCT APPT_DATE)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS CNT
```

EDIT 1 : change to CROSS APPLY (DISTINCT with OVER() is not allowed)

```
FROM #EC e
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT APPT_DATE) as CNT
    FROM   #EC x
    WHERE  x.cust_id = e.cust_id
    AND    x.emp_id  = e.emp_id
) c
```

Comment: `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.`

Comment: oh . . forgotten about that

Answer (score 0):

May be something like below should help:

```
select ec.cust_id, ec.emp_name, ec.emp_id, t.cnt, ec.APPT_DATE, ec.Procedure_Code
from #EC ec
join
(
    SELECT cust_id, emp_id ,COUNT(distinct APPT_DATE) CNT
    FROM #EC
    group BY cust_id, emp_id
) t
on ec.cust_id = t.cust_id and ec.emp_id = t.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I see from the comments that the count of dates should be distinct by both `cust_id` and `emp_id`..

```sql
SELECT cust_id
       ,emp_name
       ,emp_id
       ,oat1.Count_Appt_Date
       ,APPT_DATE
       ,Procedure_Code 
FROM #EC
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ec2.cust_id
                  , ec2.emp_id
                  , COUNT(DISTINCT(CONVERT(date, ec2.[APPT_DATE]))) AS Count_Appt_Date
             FROM #EC ec2
             WHERE ec2.cust_id = #EC.cust_id
               AND ec2.emp_id = #EC.emp_id
             GROUP BY ec2.cust_id, ec2.emp_id) oat1
ORDER BY cust_id
```